# Where to initialize Google Cloud Messaging in my Android app?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) it is done in an activity but my app has more than one activity, and I want an app-wide GCM system and not only for one activity.

I think there are 2 possibilities:

1) Initialization in the app class. The problem with that is that the GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(...) needs an activity.

2) Initialization in the main activity. The problem with that is that it's possible that the app starts with another activity and not with the main activity.

Where to initialize GCM?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to initialize it. `GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance` already returns a singleton instance of GCM, so you can call this method where ever you need the instance. You don't need to store a reference to this instance in any of your classes.

> public static synchronized GoogleCloudMessaging getInstance (Context context)
>
> Return the singleton instance of GCM.

Note that in the documentation you are referring to, this method is called both from the activity (for registration) and from the intent service (for checking the message type).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create a singleton class and have your initialization there? And depending on which activity needs the service, you can get the singleton instance and use it.